# Does MySQL accept ORDER BY "nothing" LIMIT "all" when I only want to get number of results in a search query?

Tags: mysql, search, sql-order-by, limit

I have ported a search from Coldfusion into a MySQL stored procedure.

The actual search is run twice on the site. Once to get the number of records, the 2nd time to get the actual results to display.

So both MySQL syntax differ in the last two lines:

Get no of records:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) ...
 GROUP BY a, b, c
 HAVING ...
```

Actual results:

```
 SELECT "rows"...
 GROUP BY a, b, c
 HAVING ... 
 ORDER BY var1, var2
 LIMIT var_start, var_end
```

**My question**:
Since I need to run this twice, is there a way to at least use the same stored procedure = can I add default values to order/grouping **"ORDER BY 'nothing' LIMIT 'all'**, and a parameter to the SELECT?

Sort of like an if statement

```
WHERE 1
AND IF( var_x = '', '.', var_x = some_value )
```

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is wrong - you shouldn't ask the MySQL engine to actually return the rows, and then count them, you should ask MySQL to count them directly:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ...
GROUP BY a, b, c
HAVING ...
```

Trying to shoe-horn both record *count* and record *retrieval* in the same SQL statement or stored procedure is an unnecessary optimisation.

Comment: I'm selecting count(*) in the first query... so the queries do differ in SELECT and ORDER/LIMIT. So should I do two storedprocs?

Comment: Yes, you should do two stored procs.  [ I note then that what you originally said in the question isn't strictly true - the query _does_ also vary in the first line... ]

Comment: yeah. I'm editing the question right now. Ok. Two storedprocs then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use extra parameters with the use of count(*) if it's just the number of rows you want.

```
SELECT count(a) as number_of_a, count(b) as number_of b ...
 GROUP BY a, b, c
 HAVING ... 
 ORDER BY var1, var2
 LIMIT var_start, var_end
```

Comment: Hm. I always thought search needs to run twice. Trying this.

Comment: Ok. @Alnitak is correct, I need separate storedprocs. Thanks for the tip though. I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at sql_calc_found_rows?

```
select sql_calc_found_rows mytable.* ...
```

Comment: Going with two stored procs. Thanks for the tip.